# How to customize zbar sdk's UIImagePickerView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, barcode

Iam working on barcode reder app which reads barcode and display it's data using zbar Sdk.

Now client wants to customize the square bracket which appears when camera auto focus the barcode,
  my question is that is it possible to customize it,

Thanks [image: client wnats the focus bar should appear as shown in image red and green]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to customize it, but it's not very documented. Afaik you only have APIs for setting its color and so on. If you want to do further customization, you'll need to re-implement that part yourself.

The code for the built-in tracking can be found here: http://zbar.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/zbar/zbar/file/443c9f0e3c8f/iphone

Comment: can u tell me in this api which class contain the auto focus code??

Comment: The auto focusing is done automatically by the camera frameworks in iOS.

Answer (score -1):

This will disable the autofocus property in zbar sdk
`reader.tracksSymbols=FALSE;`